# firestore: How to add a subclass into an event reference in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

For example, I have a cloud function :

```
exports.searchWordAdd = functions.firestore.document('WordSearchIndex/{wordId}').onCreate((event) => {
});
```

I want add a subclass and documents under the event.data.ref, but the DocumentReference doesn't have a function of collection. How can I get a subcollection reference based on the `event.data.ref`?

Answer (score 0):

The `event.data` is a [`DeltaDocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.firestore.DeltaDocumentSnapshot), which has the `id` of the document as a property. With that you can compose the path to the subcollection and then request it through the Firebase Admin SDK:

```
var id = event.data().id;
var subcollection = admin.firestore().collection(`WordSearchIndex/${id}/subcollection`)
```

If you just want to get a reference to the collection, that is even simpler:

```
var collection = admin.firestore().collection("WordSearchIndex")
```

Or without requiring the Admin SDK (which may be what you're looking for) with:

```
var collection = event.data().ref.parent;
```

Really helpful here are the [API reference docs for `DeltaDocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.firestore.DeltaDocumentSnapshot), its [`ref` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.firestore.DeltaDocumentSnapshot#ref), which then leads to [`DocumentReference.parent`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.8.x/DocumentReference#parent).

Comment: Not forgetting that you also have the document ID as a parameter of the function... `event.params.wordId` ;)

Comment: Good one. Yet another way. :-)